# TypeError: "Set type is unordered" in OSMnx isochrones example

Tags: pandas, geopandas, osmnx

Running the [OSMnx isochrones example](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/master/notebooks/13-isolines-isochrones.ipynb), get a TypeError: "Set type is unordered" on the last cell.

Any idea what's going wrong?

OSMnx 0.15.1 on Python 3.8.5, Pandas 1.1.1, GeoPandas 0.8.1.

It works as expected with Pandas 1.0.5, but fails with Pandas 1.1 or 1.1.1

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
     26     return isochrone_polys
     27 
---> 28 isochrone_polys = make_iso_polys(G, edge_buff=25, node_buff=0, infill=True)
     29 fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G, show=False, close=False, edge_color='#999999', edge_alpha=0.2, node_size=0)
     30 for polygon, fc in zip(isochrone_polys, iso_colors):

 in make_iso_polys(G, edge_buff, node_buff, infill)
      5 
      6         node_points = [Point((data['x'], data['y'])) for node, data in subgraph.nodes(data=True)]
----> 7         nodes_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'id': subgraph.nodes()}, geometry=node_points)
      8         nodes_gdf = nodes_gdf.set_index('id')
      9 

~/miniconda3/envs/osmnx-examples/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/geodataframe.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     87         crs = kwargs.pop("crs", None)
     88         geometry = kwargs.pop("geometry", None)
---> 89         super(GeoDataFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
     90 
     91         # need to set this before calling self['geometry'], because

~/miniconda3/envs/osmnx-examples/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    466 
    467         elif isinstance(data, dict):
--> 468             mgr = init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    469         elif isinstance(data, ma.MaskedArray):
    470             import numpy.ma.mrecords as mrecords

~/miniconda3/envs/osmnx-examples/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype)
    281             arr if not is_datetime64tz_dtype(arr) else arr.copy() for arr in arrays
    282         ]
--> 283     return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    284 
    285 

~/miniconda3/envs/osmnx-examples/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in arrays_to_mgr(arrays, arr_names, index, columns, dtype, verify_integrity)
     81 
     82         # don't force copy because getting jammed in an ndarray anyway
---> 83         arrays = _homogenize(arrays, index, dtype)
     84 
     85         columns = ensure_index(columns)

~/miniconda3/envs/osmnx-examples/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in _homogenize(data, index, dtype)
    349                     val = dict(val)
    350                 val = lib.fast_multiget(val, oindex._values, default=np.nan)
--> 351             val = sanitize_array(
    352                 val, index, dtype=dtype, copy=False, raise_cast_failure=False
    353             )

~/miniconda3/envs/osmnx-examples/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/construction.py in sanitize_array(data, index, dtype, copy, raise_cast_failure)
    450         subarr = _try_cast(arr, dtype, copy, raise_cast_failure)
    451     elif isinstance(data, abc.Set):
--> 452         raise TypeError("Set type is unordered")
    453     elif lib.is_scalar(data) and index is not None and dtype is not None:
    454         data = maybe_cast_to_datetime(data, dtype)

TypeError: Set type is unordered
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue in the example. It it initializes a data frame with `subgraph.nodes()`

```py
nodes_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'id': subgraph.nodes()}, geometry=node_points)
```

`subgraph.nodes()` is a `NodeView`, [which behaves both like a dictionary and a set](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/release/migration_guide_from_1.x_to_2.0.html). These are unordered types, but Pandas needs an ordered collection such as a numpy array or list. Pandas 1.1 introduced a type check to catch this in issue [32582](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/32582).

A workaround is to explicitly convert the `NodeView` to a `list`:

```py
nodes_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'id': list(subgraph.nodes())}, geometry=node_points)
```

I submitted a [bug](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/issues/36) and a [PR](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/pull/37), which has already been accepted, so this is no longer an issue.